# jquery how to store the last mouse trigger 

Tags: jquery, slideshow, intervals

I have a slideshow. When I hover on it, the interval is cleared.When I hover out, the interval starts.
The interval function pushes the active class (which was added on mouseover to one of the li's) to the next li. 
 To start it, I have to trigger the mouseover function on one of  the slideshow li's. When I hoer out, I clear the interval but at the same time remove the active class as the mouse is no longer over any li's. So, so far, I have achieved that the slideshow starts again, but only from the first li. How do I store the last li mouseover and then start the slideshow from there?
Below is my code...

```
var timer, autoAdvance = function(){$("#accordion-slider li:first").addClass('first');$("#accordion-slider li:last").addClass('last');var currentSlide=$("#accordion-slider .active");var nextSlide=$("#accordion-slider .active").next();(!currentSlide.is('.last'))?$(nextSlide).trigger('mouseover'):$("#accordion-slider .first").trigger('mouseover')/*.next().addClass('next')*/;}
var timer = setInterval(autoAdvance,2000);

$().ready(function() { 
    //using kwicks plugin for slides
$('#accordion-slider').kwicks({  
    max : 500,  
    spacing : 5,
});


$('#accordion-slider').hover(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function () {
    timer = setInterval(autoAdvance, 2000);
    $("ul#accordion-slider li:first").trigger('mouseover');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that your approach is the best approach. But it's all a learning curve i guess. To store data use the data() attribute. you can use the data on the accordian-slider like so

```
//-- set
$("ul#accordian-slider").data("somekey", "somevalue");

//-- get
$("ul#accordian-slider").data("somekey");
```